# How to change the end-effector position?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made a moveit model of a manipulator and i want. I assign the end-effector as the last link. I want to change the end-effector tip position without editing the URDF file, like adding a new tool. Is it possible??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261692/how-to-change-the-end-effector-position-??/) by [Milan Michael](https://answers.ros.org/users/30378/milan-michael/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, endeffectors in moveit move groups can be defined only with links and joints that belong to the loaded URDF model.

---

Originally posted by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) with karma: 351 on 2017-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0